# Plotting objects on a lattice using Show

Tags: plotting, slideshows

I can show some graphs, objects, and arrows using Show as bellow:

```
Show[a,b,c,d,...]
```

The output of above code is a picture, centered at (0,0).
I want to draw a picture in which above output is repeated on the sites of a square lattice with equal distances(distance=2). The total number of sites is equal to N^2. 
How can I do that?

First answer doesn't work in my case:

```
n = 3;
ger = Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, {2.8, 2.8}]}, PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style[Large]}];
bj = Show[ger, {des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}], des /. Line[a_] -> {Red, Polygon[a]}, des}, {des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}], des /. Line[a_] -> {Blue, Polygon[a]}, des}, {des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}],des /. Line[a_] -> {Darker[Red], Polygon[a]}, des}, {des = Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.7}]}], des /. Line[a_] -> {Blue, Polygon[a]}, des}]
objects = Graphics /@ Thread[{ColorData[5, "ColorList"][[;; 9]], bj}];

Show[MapIndexed[Graphics[Translate[#[[1]], 2 #2 - 1]] &, Partition[objects, n], {2}], Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Maybe you want [GraphicsGrid](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html)?

Comment: what is `a`  in `Polygon[a]`?

Comment: It is used in Line @Sumit

Comment: @Jens it works but it also print axis of each plot

Comment: not exactly related to your problem - I think you can simplify your plot by using `Show[
 PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, Pi/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}] /. Line[a_] -> {Blue, Polygon[a]},
 PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, Pi/2, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}] /. Line[a_] -> {Red, Polygon[a]},
 PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, Pi, 3/2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}] /. 
  Line[a_] -> {Darker[Red], Polygon[a]},
 PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 3/2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}] /. Line[a_] -> {Red, Polygon[a]}
 , Frame -> True]`

Comment: I need the white region in the center @Sumit

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 3;
objects = Graphics /@ Thread[{ColorData[5, "ColorList"][[;; 9]], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}]; 
Show[MapIndexed[Graphics[Translate[#[[1]], 2 #2 - 1]] &, 
       Partition[objects, n], {2}], Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Maybe this:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}], 
    des /. Line[a_] -> {Red, Polygon[a]}, des}, 
  {des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}], 
    des /. Line[a_] -> {Blue, Polygon[a]}, des}, 
  {des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}], 
    des /. Line[a_] -> {Darker[Red], Polygon[a]}, des}} /. 
  Rule[Axes, _] :> Rule[Axes, False]]
```

[image]

If you need to add the row of White ellipsis add

```
{des = Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.7}]}],  des, des}
```

after the third `{des = PolarPlot[...],..}` in the first argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work in my case

Comment: @Monaphys, it would be very useful if you could explain **how** it doesn't work in your case; e.g. how did you use this approach in your case, what did you get?  If you get error messages what are they?  Obviously, more information about your `a, b, c,...` is needed to find out what went wrong with this method or what would be right method.

Comment: I added the code to the question. Could you please check how can use your method in this case?